# bruteforce on aes 256 cbc mode

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

i have a series of encrypted text , they encrypted by aes 256 bit cbc mode
for every encrypted text there is an iv that i have them also
and i know its algorithm is aes 256 bit cbc mode
i can generate new encrypted values that i know what is plain text, but the iv would be different
i have something else named mac that i don't know what it is, it is 64 character in hex format
by the way i know the algorithm is for one of laravel plugins named elocryptfive
can i do any attack on it to find key or decrypt values?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question seems good, but is not a coding/programming question. Please edit the question, and ask what exact problem you have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a theoretical crypto question - probably better suited for [http://crypto.stackexchange.com/](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/). But probably also needs a bit more editing also - there's a mix of details in the narrative that are difficult to pick out, so it's unclear exactly what information you *have*.

Comment: No, you can't brute-force AES-256 with current supercomputers and current knowledge. It would take beyond the heat death of the universe. Except if you know that the chosen key is bad (is it derived from a password? is it hardcoded in ASCII somewhere?).

Comment: i know the key is base64 encoded and i know its length